# How to re use a variable from an IIFE to another using plain JS?

Tags: javascript

I wrote a function, `initialize` that immediately invokes two other functions within an object. I want to reuse the `boardXs` variable on `toggleSymbol`. Therefore, I thought of returning it to `initialize`'s scope hoping it would work.

```
const game = {
    initialize: (function() {
        (function hideX() {
            let boardXs = document.querySelectorAll('#ghost > div');
            for (let i = 0; i < boardXs.length; i++) {
                boardXs[i].innerHTML = " ";
            };
            return {boardXs};
        })(),

        (function toggleSymbol() {
            console.log(boardXs)
        })();
    });
}
```

As I run `game.initialize()` in the console, `hideX` works but an error is thrown in the console: "boardXs is not defined".

What is going on? How can I use variables amongst IIFEs?
For the sake of learning, I'd like to continue using this IIFE setup, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this if you are returning the object from `hideX` and use it in `toggleSymbol`.

If you are returning the object from the `hideX`, then you need to store the returned value in a variable and use that variable in scope or its nested scope.

```js
const game = {
  initialize: (function() {
  
    // Grab object in result
    const result = (function hideX() {
      let boardXs = document.querySelectorAll('#ghost > div');
      for (let i = 0; i < boardXs.length; i++) {
        boardXs[i].innerHTML = " ";
      };
      return {
        boardXs
      };
    })();

    // use here
    (function toggleSymbol() {
      console.log(result)
    })();
  })
}

game.initialize();
```

```html
<div id="ghost">
  <div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @emirand Is this what you're trying